# What is the cost function (performance index) for 2nd order ODE systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control

I have the following 2nd order linear system with appropriate initial conditions.

$$\textbf{X}''(t)+\textbf{A}(t)\textbf{X}'(t)+\textbf{B}(t)\textbf{X}(t)=\textbf{F}(t)+\textbf{C}(t)\textbf{U}(t)$$
$\textbf{X}$ is a unknown vector.

$\textbf{A, B, C, F}$ are time varying matrices.

$\textbf{U}(t)$ is a control input matrix.

I wonder what is the cost function (performance index) for the following 2nd order linear system for finding optimal control function $\textbf{U}(t)$?

But I didn' t find enough reference books, articles etc. (Do you have good references?)

Is it the following functional, right?

$$J=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t_f}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{QX}+\dot{\textbf{X}}^T\textbf{R}\dot{\textbf{X}}+\textbf{U}^T\textbf{ZU})dt$$

where $\textbf{Q,R,Z}$ are the semipositive matrices.

Comment: What is the question? Yes, $J$ is a cost function which punishes $X$, $\dot X$ or $U$ being large. Are you sure these are matrices and not just vectors? I would expect a trace in the cost function to make it scalar.

Comment: I edited the question. Can you tell more your opinion about trace in the cost function?

Comment: Now the products in the integrand are scalars, no need for a trace. It is still not clear what the question is. You want to minimize $J$ under some initial conditions for the ODE. This is not as easy as for a first order equation, but you should have sources for the solution process.

Comment: I want to find optimal control function $U(t)$, so firstly I must define a cost function for the linear system. What makes the 2nd order system so difficult compared to 1st order systems?If you offer some references for 2nd order system, I will be very happy , Dear LutzL

Comment: I have no references, but believe to remember one expert mentioning that control problems for second order ODE lead to higher index differential-algebraic equations. Meaning that a naive treatment may overlook so-called "hidden constraints".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write the second order differential equation as a first order using

$$
\dot{z} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ -B(t) & -A(t) \end{bmatrix} z + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ F(t) \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ C(t) \end{bmatrix} u
$$

where $z=\begin{bmatrix}x^\top & \dot{x}^\top \end{bmatrix}^\top$.

A quadratic cost function can also be generalized to

$$
J =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t_f} \begin{bmatrix}z \\ u\end{bmatrix}^\top \!M \begin{bmatrix}z \\ u\end{bmatrix} dt
$$

with $M=M^\top\succeq0$ plus come extra constraints similar for [LQR](https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lqr.html#f3-254493).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The functional $$J=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t_f}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{QX}+\dot{\textbf{X}}^T\textbf{R}\dot{\textbf{X}}+\textbf{U}^T\textbf{ZU})dt$$ is the performance index for the 2nd order, right?

Comment: @1_student Only if you ignore cross-terms between $\textbf{X}$, $\dot{\textbf{X}}$ and $\textbf{U}$.

Comment: if we don' t ignore cross-terms, what is the performance index? do you have good references?

Comment: @1_student the performance index $$\begin{bmatrix}z \\ u\end{bmatrix}^\top \!M \begin{bmatrix}z \\ u\end{bmatrix}$$ is just a more convenient way of writing $$z^\top Q\,z+2\,z^\top N\,u+u^\top R\,u$$ namely this can be obtained by using $$M=\begin{bmatrix}Q & N \\ N^\top & R\end{bmatrix}.$$